# Summation of distinct largest and second largest

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, integer, max

I have trying to solve a problem in codechef on array of the summation of distinct largest and second largest. But it shows me error. I have tried but couldn't debug it yet. Would you help me, please?
The problem is following:
You are given an array **A** of **N** integers.
Find the maximum sum of two distinct integers in the array.
Sample Input:

```
4
3
4 1 6
7
3 7 2 1 1 5 3
5
8 2 9 4 9
2
1 2
```

Sample Output:

```
10
12
17
3
```

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while (T--)
    {
        int ara[1000], n, i, t;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int largest, secL;
        // input
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &ara[i]);
        }
        if (ara[0] > ara[1])
            largest = ara[0], secL = ara[1];
        else
            largest = ara[1], secL = ara[0];
        for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            t = ara[i];
            if (t > largest && )
                secL = largest,largest = t ;
            else if (t > secL && t<largest)
                secL = t;
        }

        printf("%d\n",largest + secL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The online compiler shows:
[image: WA in 1,2,3 cases]

Though my program works fine for the given input.

Actually I wanna to know the bugs in my code.

Comment: Why do you have `int ara[1000]`? There is no link given to the CodeChef problem to see its contraints. Also, what is `if (t > largest && )`?

Comment: You have implicitly assumed that no list will have more than 1000 elements. And you've implicitly assumed that the results will fit in an `int`. Whether these are reasonable assumptions depends on the inputs and their constraints.

Comment: Please don't do `largest = ara[1], secL = ara[0];` to be lazy. Use `{ largest = ara[1]; secL = ara[0]; }`.

Comment: *I wanna to know the bugs in my code*... you failed to check that the first two array elements are *distinct*. If the first two elements are the largest, and the same value you will give the wrong answer.

Comment: `if (t > largest && )`  ??? The code you provied doesn't compile.  Please correct it, or it will be impossible to help you. You have no bugs yet... you have compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails when the first two elements are the same, and the largest.
You don't need an array: you can solve with a single parse of the incoming data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while (T--) {
        int val, n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int largest = INT_MIN, secL = INT_MIN;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &val);
            if (largest < val) {
                secL = largest;
                largest = val;
            }
            else if(secL < val && largest > val)
                secL = val;
        }
        printf("%d\n", largest + secL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a typo in the if statement

```
if (t > largest && )
```

So the program shall not compile.

Nevertheless your approach is logical wrong. If the first two elements of the array are equal each other and are largest elements of the array then the result will be incorrect.

You could write for example something like the following:

```
int first, second;
int second_present = 0;

first = ara[0];

for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
{
    if ( first < ara[i] )
    {
        second_present = 1;
        second = first;
        first = ara[i];
    }
    else if ( ( ara[i] < first ) && ( second_present == 0 || second < ara[i] ) )
    {
        second_present = 1;
        second = ara[i];
    }
}

if ( second_present ) printf( "%lld\n", ( long long int )first + second );
else puts( "There is no unique second largest element." );
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you don't need to have a 1000 element array to store the elements, as you are not using the array elements once processed.  In my opinion your code has these flags:  (i shall limit myself to the inner loop, for brevity)

```
        int ara[1000], n, i, t;
```

- the array `ara[1000]` is not needed, but an array of just two elements to hold
  the largest two  elements should be a must, as you complicate things by trying to make all the possible comparisons, and your code doesn't escalate in case you are asked for the largest N elements.  IMHO, having a N element array and
  inserting the last read value in the appropiate place would be faster (you will see that your failing tests probably incur in a time penalty, due to the two passes you do on the input: one to read and store, the next to get the
  two largest numbers)  You also don't check the scanf result, so if you are given input that is not parseable as a number, you can get into trouble, because you don't ask `scanf` if it has read the numbers correctly.

Your code, anyway, doesn't compile, as you have a malformed expression in line 24 (ending in `&&` which is incorrect syntax) so I cannot run your code with the input you provide. I have made this approach, although, that runs correctly with your input, using the `NELEM` array approach, and making a one pass through the data.  Elements are inserted in the approipate place in the array, and so, just adding the largest elements, you can consider an input of just one element, which will probably fail in your code (you assume that all inputs will be of two elements or more, but you don't specify that as a requirement)  the insertion sorting method is appropiate as we don't allow the array to grow over 2 elements and makes comparisons simpler (you don't have to compare all elements with all, just skip if the element is equal or less than every element)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define F(_fmt) __FILE__":%d: "_fmt, __LINE__
#define ERR(_efmt, ...) do {                      \
        fprintf(stderr, F(_efmt), ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                       \
    } while (0)

/* number of elements we want to add, change this freely */
#define NELEM   2

int main()
{
    int N;

    int res = scanf("%d", &N);
    if (res < 1)
        ERR("couldn't scan number of tests\n");

    for (int t = 1; t <= N; t++) {

        int array[NELEM], array_n = 0;
        int n, res = scanf("%d", &n);
        if (res < 1) {
            ERR("test #%d: couldnt scan number of elements of array\n", t);
        }

        /* read it, try to insert it in the proper place */
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int el;
            res = scanf("%d", &el);
            if (res < 1) {
                ERR("test #%d: cannot read element #%d\n", t, i);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < array_n; j++) {
                if (el > array[j]) {
                    /* shift all elements to the end of the array */
                    for (int k = j; k < array_n && k < NELEM; k++) {
                        /* exchange el <-> array[j] */
                        int temp = el;
                        el = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            /* only add up last element to array if smaller than NELEM */
            if (array_n < NELEM)
                array[array_n++] = el;
        }
        /* add the array elements */
        int accum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array_n; i++) {
            accum += array[i];
        }
        printf("%d\n", accum);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```